# problem with kotlin coroutine runBlocking and stateIn

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

val numbers: StateFlow<Int> = (1..100).asFlow()
    .onEach { delay(100) }
    .let {
        runBlocking {
            it.stateIn(this)
        }
    }

fun main(){
    println("hello")
    println(numbers.value)
    println("bye")
}
```

I expect that `main` function finish only in 100ms (wait for first emission)
but second print happens when all items emitted (takes about 100*100 ms) and also prints last item instead of first one!

am I missing something or it is a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s expected behaviour when you use `runBlocking`, because `runBlocking` won’t return until all of its child jobs have completed.

In other words, the `numbers` property won’t return a value until the entire flow has terminated. This is because calling `stateIn(scope)` launches a job inside the scope that collects all the items from the flow. You can see where this happens in the [source code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/3574c2feca23c3e8a1ad00b5bf92e2bf04d95060/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators/Share.kt#L325-L354).

If you want to allow the `numbers` flow to emit values concurrently with your `main` function, you'll need to use a scope in which both functions can run together. For example, you could call `runBlocking` in the `main` function, and pass the scope as a receiver for the `numbers` property:

```kotlin
val CoroutineScope.numbers: StateFlow<Int> get() = (1..100).asFlow()
    .onEach { delay(100) }
    .let {
        it.stateIn(this)
    }

fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("hello")
    println(numbers.value)
    println("bye")
}
```

Comment: where you said `because runBlocking won’t return until all of its child jobs have completed.`I imagine that there is an internal coroutine (related to scope) created inside stateIn block that only completes ,when all items are emitted ? is that true ?

Comment: Exactly . You can actually see it in the [source code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/3574c2feca23c3e8a1ad00b5bf92e2bf04d95060/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators/Share.kt#L325-L354). In line 337 it calls `launch` to create a job that collects all the values from the flow. I'll update my answer to include that.